# Magento 2. Ui component increase input size

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

- I have a ui-component generated form.
- Inside the form a datetime input is generated.
- The value shown is truncated because the value is bigger than the input.

This is my input definition

```
<field name="created_at">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Created At</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">issue</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**This is a ps of the view.**

[image]

**How can I modify the input size to display the whole value?**

Comment: increase width size

Comment: you mean from css?